# comparing date with different seasons in php

Tags: php, date

hi i stored a date that is taken from form in a variable using php and now i want to check whether the date is in the season or not..
the code i written is as follows:

```
$year = 2012;
$month1 = $_POST["month1"];
$date = $_POST["date"];
$result = "{$year}/{$month1}/{$date}";
echo $result;
```

and now

```
// finding first saturday in febraury
    $saturday = strtotime('First Saturday '.date('F o', mktime(0,0,0, $month, 1, $year)));
    echo "this is the first saturday in the given year:";
    echo date('Y/m/d', $saturday);

 // calculating first 12 weeks after the first saturday
    echo "<br/>";
    $season1 = strtotime ( '+12 week' , $saturday);
    echo "<br/>this is the first season:";
    echo date('Y/m/d', $season1);
    echo "<br/>";

 // calculating the one week gap after the first 12 weeks
    $season2 = strtotime ('+1 week' , $season1);
    echo "<br/>this is the first week break:";
    echo date('Y/m/d', $season2);
    echo "<br/>";
```

Here what i need to do is to check whether the date given by the user is in season1 or season2..for doing so i tried as

```
if ($result <= $season1)
    {
     echo "League yet to be opened";
    }
    else 
    {
    echo "league 1 is opened";
    }
```

but the condition is not checking here, and like wise i need to check the date entered by the user with 8 seasons how can i do that....any help is much appreciated....thanks in advance..

Comment: can anyone help me out plz....

Comment: Please, clarify, how is your seasons defined

Comment: from the above code you can see that $season1 is the first season, $season2 is the second season like wise i have upto $season8. I need to get the date from the user and have to check with all the seasons and tell him in what season he is in now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advice you use such organisation of code and logic

Define current date from POSTed

Don't forget to became sure data is safe

Year, month and date (day) MUST be numerical, for this logic to work.

```
$year = 2012;
$month1 = $_POST["month1"];
$date = $_POST["date"];
```

Define your seasons array

```
$seasons = array(
   1 => array(
              'season_name' => 'first_season',
              'year_start' => 2012, 'year_end' => 2012, 
              'month_start' => 1, 'month_end' => 2, 
              'day_start' => 10, 'day_end' => 20
              ), 
   2 => array(
              'season_name' => 'second_season',
              'year_start' => 2012, 'year_end' => 2012, 
              'month_start' => 2, 'month_end' => 3, 
              'day_start' => 30, 'day_end' => 15
              ) 
 );
```

Process data to define season

```
$season_match = array();
foreach($seasons as $season){
   if($year >= $season['year_start']) && if($year <= $season['year_end']){
       if($month >= $season['month_start']) && if($season<= $season['month_end']){
           if($date >= $season['date_start']) && if($season<= $season['date_end']){
               $seasons_match[] = $season['season_name'];
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Test for errors and echo resulting season

```
if(count($season_match) == 0){
   echo 'Date is out of any season';
}
esleif(count($season_match) >1){
   echo 'ERROR: Date can be for more then one season at once';
}
else{
   echo $season_match; // This is the name of our season!
}
```

It's general logic for simple and clear solution of your task, I haven't tested it.

Comment: I added some minor fixes (wrong names and such), now it looks correct. Glad it helped. Btw, it's better add upvote for the unswers you like, because some people hunt for rating :-)